# How to change toggle to icon click (for switching to dark mode)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've dark mode enabled on the website. It currently has a toggle switch, which changes the layout from light to dark and vice versa.

It is using the following code:

```js
const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]');
const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
if (currentTheme) {
  document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', currentTheme);
  if (currentTheme === 'dark') {
    toggleSwitch.checked = true;
  }
}

function switchTheme(e) {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
    localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');
  } else {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
    localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');
  }
}
toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', switchTheme, false);
```

```html
<div class="theme-switch-wrapper">
  <label class="theme-switch" for="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/>
                        <div class="slider round"></div>
                    </label>
  <em>DARK</em>
  <strong>MODE</strong>
</div>
```

Now I want to upgrade to an icon click. For example, if there is light mode enabled, the icon for dark mode should be seen upon clicking it, the user will get dark mode on. Same, if dark mode is enabled, the icon for the light mode to be displayed, and if the user clicks it, the light mode is activated.

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Just put 2 icons there and hide one if the opposite mode is enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the HTMl make a new image as a lable:

```
<label class="theme-switch" for="checkbox">
        <img width="30" id="switcher" src="">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
        <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>
```

then you can use the set attribute to switch the source

```
<script>
    const switcher = document.querySelector("#switcher");
    switcher.setAttribute('src', 'https://vectorified.com/images/switch-button-icon-19.png');

    const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]');
    const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
    if (currentTheme) {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', currentTheme);
        if (currentTheme === 'dark') {
            toggleSwitch.checked = true;
        }
    }

    function switchTheme(e) {
        if (e.target.checked) {
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
            localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');
            switcher.setAttribute('src', 'https://vectorified.com/images/switch-button-icon-19.png');
        } else {
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
            localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');
            switcher.setAttribute('src', 'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/37/37474.png');
        }
    }
    toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', switchTheme, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It worked in my testing. Can you share me how I can add title to the image, for example, switch to dark mode when someone hover over the icon.

Once again, thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the toggle switch to a `button` element with an icon inside.

Then inside your click-handling code, you can switch out the `src` of the icon svg/image to show the other image.

```js
const darkmodeIcon = "https://uxwing.com/wp-content/themes/uxwing/download/01-user_interface/dark-mode.png"
const lightmodeIcon = "https://uxwing.com/wp-content/themes/uxwing/download/01-user_interface/light-mode.png"

const icon = document.getElementById("darkmode-icon");
icon.src = lightmodeIcon

function handleDarkModeToggle() {
  if (icon.src == darkmodeIcon) {
    icon.src = lightmodeIcon
    console.log("Toggled to Light Mode")
  } else {
    icon.src = darkmodeIcon
    console.log("Toggled to Dark Mode")
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  background: white;
  border: none;
}

img {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="handleDarkModeToggle()">
<img id="darkmode-icon"/>
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am not sure where should I put the code you've provided in my existing JS code. Can you please share with me complete script I should use including your code.

Thanks again for your help :)